# Почему django не загружает картинку?

Tags: python, django

При написании статьи я могу по желанию загрузить изображение, но, когда я это делаю, ничего не происходит
settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

detail.html

```
  <img src="{% if article.image %}{{ article.image.url }}{% endif %}">
```

models.html

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    file = models.FileField(blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

forms.py

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'image','file']
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'content/detail.html',
        {'article': article})

def list(request):
  return render(request, 'content/list.html', {
    'articles': Article.objects.all()
  })

def create_article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('list')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()
    return render(request, 'content/create.html', {'form': form})
```

create.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
  create article
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Если ты загружаешь картинку через форму, то попробуй передать параметр `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>`, если не помогло, попробуй ещё передать параметр `widget` в файле `models`. Это будет выглядеть так: `image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', widget=forms.FileInput())`

Comment: @zomaman добавление виджета даже ошибку вызывает `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'`, а без него изменений нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с вашей задачей.

Первый шаг: create.html

```
<form action="/content/create/"
```

Как я и говорил в атрибуте action должна быть ссылка на метод обработки формы.

Второй шаг: views.py

```
form = ArticleForm(request.POST,files=request.FILES)
```

Забыли обязательный аргумент, если мы что то загружаем files=request.FILES.

Третий шаг: detail.html

```
 <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.image.url }}">
```

У меня ваш проект из репозитория работает, появляется папка и в ней загруженные файлики и фото выводится в шаблоне.

Comment: не помогло. проблема в том, что картинка не загружается в папку => неоткуда её брать

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код `forms` и `views`

Comment: @Elliot13 готово, я всё добавил

Comment: хм, вроде всё должно работать. Добавьте `html` с формой загрузки картинки.

Comment: @Elliot13 добавил

Comment: А разве в form action="." в скобках не должно быть ссылки из urls.py на метод где обрабатывается форма, а у вас там точка. Покажите свой файлик urls.py. Или вы уже разобрались в проблеме?

Comment: @ZheniaKviatkivskyi если так сделать, то после заполнения формы в url просто добавится ещё одно слово create, что вызовет ошибку

Comment: @Innsmouth fisherman первый раз слышу о таком, если хотите залейте ваш проект на гит хаб например, я посмотрю, если чесно аж интересно, почему загрузка не работает.

Comment: @ZheniaKviatkivskyi [https://github.com/InnsmouthFisherman/media_files_problem]

Comment: @Innsmouth обновил свой ответ.